# The controller phases through the ground. needs help fixing it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm pretty new to Unity and I need help on fixing this code, I tried Chat Gpt many times but didn't get a good result either  way.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]
public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Max speed, in units per second, that the character moves.")]
    float speed = 9;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Acceleration while grounded.")]
    float walkAcceleration = 75;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Acceleration while in the air.")]
    float airAcceleration = 30;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Deceleration applied when the character is grounded and not attempting to move.")]
    float groundDeceleration = 70;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Max height the character will jump regardless of gravity")]
    float jumpHeight = 4;

    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    private Vector2 velocity;
    private bool grounded;

    private void Awake()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Handle character movement
        float moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float Acceleration = grounded ? walkAcceleration : airAcceleration;
        float Deceleration = grounded ? groundDeceleration : 0;

        // Calculate velocity based on input
        if (moveInput != 0)
        {
            velocity.x = Mathf.MoveTowards(velocity.x, speed * moveInput, Acceleration * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            velocity.x = Mathf.MoveTowards(velocity.x, 0, Deceleration * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Apply gravity
        velocity.y += Physics2D.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;

        // Move the character
        transform.Translate(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        // Handle jumping
        if (grounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(2 * jumpHeight * Mathf.Abs(Physics2D.gravity.y));
        }

        // Detect collisions and update grounded status
        grounded = false;
        Collider2D[] hits = Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll(transform.position, boxCollider.size, 0);

        foreach (Collider2D hit in hits)
        {
            if (hit == boxCollider)
            {
                continue;
            }

            ColliderDistance2D colliderDistance = hit.Distance(boxCollider);

            if (colliderDistance.isOverlapped)
            {
                transform.Translate(colliderDistance.pointA - colliderDistance.pointB);

                if (Vector2.Angle(colliderDistance.normal, Vector2.up) < 90 && velocity.y < 0)
                {
                    grounded = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Help is much appreciated, Thanks.

I tried several things like changing orders but when I do it I cant jump sometimes and when I can jump the the controller phases through.

Comment: transform.Translate would ignore physics though right.

Comment: when you deal with physics you do not want to do anything via `Transform` but rather go through a `Rigidbody2D`

Comment: also btw instead of using `Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll` and then check and skip your own collider + have an additional distance check .. you can rather simply go directly through [`boxCollider.OverlapCollider(contactFilter, results)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OverlapCollider.html)

Comment: much thanks for the help, Really appreciate it.